# wildfly Applicaton deployment take too long

Tags: deployment, wildfly

I have a strange issue concerning application deployment in WildFly 8.1.0

At the begining application deployment was fast but today it became very slow
I see in the server logs that it spend 5 minutes between org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version and org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect lines

```
17:14:07,417 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
17:19:08,034 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

and there is no error message...

Once started the application run without problems

I have really no idea what to do

I made a lot of changes on all layers of the application (JSF, JPA...) before to notice that

Comment: Have you tried turning on debug logging to possibly see what's happening?

Comment: Are you doing JPA database schema validation/update on start. And if db is slow to respond it would explain this.

Comment: * The debug mode don't show more informations
* table generation strategy: none and validation strategy: auto but take 5 minutes even if set to none

Comment: I have re install  NetBeans and WildFly and the problem remain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I move the database at localhost the problem desappear
It was a problem of network communication speed
The problem appear when we added a lot of entities so a lot of tables...

Thanks ctomc for your question